# Log-In Automation

Tags: python, http, automation

I am trying to write a Python script that will automate logging in to a web-client. This is to automatically log-in to the web-client with a provided user name and password. Below is my Python code:

```
import httplib 
import urllib 
import urllib2 
header = {
    'Host' : 'localhost.localdomain',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Origin' : 'localhost.localdomain', #check what origin does
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20131029 Firefox/17.0',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer' : 'http://localhost.localdomain/mail/index.php/mail/auth/processlogin',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cookie' : 'atmail6=tdl3ckcf4oo88fsgvt5cetoc92'
}
content = {
    'emailName' : 'pen.test.clin',
    'emailDomain' : '',
    'emailDomainDefault' : '',
    'cssStyle' : 'original',
    'email' : 'pen.test.clin',
    'password' : 'aasdjk34',
    'requestedServer' : '',
    'MailType' : 'IMAP',
    'Language' : ''
}

def runBruteForceTesting():
    url="http://localhost.localdomain/mail/index.php/mail/auth/processlogin"
    for i in range (0,100):
        data = urllib.urlencode(content)
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url, request)
        print 'hi'
        print request, response
runBruteForceTesting()
```

However: I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dheerajg/Desktop/python/log.py", line 39, in <module>
    runBruteForceTesting()
  File "C:/Users/dheerajg/Desktop/python/log.py", line 35, in runBruteForceTesting
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 402, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1123, in do_request_
    'Content-length', '%d' % len(data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 229, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: __len__
```

Answer (score 1):

The `request` object that you received from `urllib2.Request` does not have a
`__len__` method ; in your context, it means you're calling `urllib2.urlopen` 
with a wrong second argument.

Looking at documentation, it is written it needs a string:

> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed.

So what about calling `urlopen` like this:

> response = urllib2.urlopen(url, request.get_data())

?